# Air Canada personal item sizer size?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, air-canada

The [Air Canada rules](https://www.aircanada.com/no/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/carry-on.html) only permit a 16cm wide bag which is not a lot. of storage allowance.

RyanAir gives 20cm, United gives 22cm... how big is the sizer for Air Canada?

Comment: Note: there is no weight limit (if one can lift weights without limits). Ryanair has just one (or two) type of airplanes. I noticed that airlines with Dash tent to have lower limit (I assume mostly enforced only on such airplanes, just because lack of physical space, OTOH it is standard on Dash that you put "hand baggage" below the cabin). [I also never seen a sizer (or measuring) the personal item]

Comment: https://c8.alamy.com/comp/AMHYCT/miami-florida-airport-air-canada-carry-on-luggage-size-information-AMHYCT.jpg you can see how there's a sizer for both items on this photo.

Comment: That photo has also 10Kg weight limit (which is not on Air Canada website). And I doubt Air Canada will use Dash in Miami. Interesting.

Comment: In 2017 February they changed the 10kg weight limit to "what you can lift" but not the sizer. Also, the sizer has nothing to do with the equipment used on the route.

Comment: What is important are the written rules that you have already linked. the physical sizer is to the reference of travelers when the ground staff need to demonstrate. ( arguing for example ) also - the sizer may *slightly* vary in dimensions in  different airports / countries because they are locally sourced ( usually from local airport authority ) at any rate they have no real meaning except reference because the final decision is that of the ground-crew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sitting at YYZ right now, and managed to scout out a (relatively) not-busy part of T1 to measure the sizers. Almost every sizer is of the old type: composed of metal tubing welded together to form a frame. I also saw a few new sizers that are powder coated black sheet metal, and look much less forgiving. Here's what I found:

### Common Style

These sizers are very forgiving, as one can insert a bag diagonally and straighten it out inside the sizer. With this method, for example, wheels on 4-wheel roller bags should poke out of the frame somewhat. Also, thicker bags that are somewhat compressible can expand once they're past the top bar, by about 25-30 mm.

[image: Air Canada carry-on sizer]
[image: Air Canada personal item sizer]

As the photo indicates, I took measurements between the top bars, side bars, and from the top of the bottom bars to the top of the top bars. This type of sizer measures **545 x 405 x 235 mm** for the carry-on bag, and **425 x 330 x 160 mm** for the personal item. (But if your bag is at all compressible and above any of these measurements, it's easy to shove it in without much force.)

### New Style

Most relevant to your question, the new style of sizer only has 4 sides for the personal item: left, right, back, and bottom. The only way to check its thickness is visually, which I suspect won't be very rigorous.

I'll try to find one that I can measure, but they're all in busy areas and not easily accessible. If I find one, I'll update this answer with a photo and proper measurements.

Comment: And I just realized this question was about personal item, not carry-on bag. I'll measure that too! Sorry!

Comment: That's amazing, the [official](https://www.aircanada.com/no/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/carry-on.html) personal item requirements is 430 x 330 x 160 and with this type of sizer there is absolutely no give to that.

Answer (score -1):

At 0:05 in this video, [Measuring up Air Canada's hard line on carry-on luggage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vg_PlA_KACA), you can see the sizer dimensions.

The Personal Item has a 16cm depth.

At 0:20, you see several close-up shots of the sizer itself.

Comment: But the video only shows the sizer's sign.  We want to see the sizer itself, so we can see whether one could potentially squeeze in a thicker bag.  Sometimes the sizer itself doesn't match the sign.

Comment: @krubo Close-ups are in the video as well.  OP asked how big is the sizer.

Comment: @krubo is right, there's nothing in this video. The answer would need to include a measuring tape either directly the sizer or something to the tone of "I squeezed a bag inside which was N cm thick".